# MySQL Trigger Error

Tags: mysql, trigger

I receive the following error when below MySQL statements are executed:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

Can anyone explain the error ?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_quiz_attempt_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON `Quiz_Attempt`    
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Quiz_Attempt_History (Q_Code, S_Email, Result)
     VALUES (old.Q_Code, old.S_Email, old.Result);  
UPDATE Quiz_Attempt_History QAH 
     SET QAH.C_Code = (SELECT C_Code FROM Quiz_Scope WHERE Q_Code = old.Q_Code), 
         QAH.S_No =   (SELECT S_No FROM Quiz_Scope WHERE Q_Code = old.Q_Code) 
     WHERE QAH.Q_Code=old.Q_Code AND QAH.S_Email=old.S_Email;   
END;
```

Comment: Did you change the delimiter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `before_quiz_attempt_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON `Quiz_Attempt`    
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Quiz_Attempt_History (Q_Code, S_Email, Result)
     VALUES (old.Q_Code, old.S_Email, old.Result);  
UPDATE Quiz_Attempt_History QAH 
     SET QAH.C_Code = (SELECT C_Code FROM Quiz_Scope WHERE Q_Code = old.Q_Code), 
         QAH.S_No =   (SELECT S_No FROM Quiz_Scope WHERE Q_Code = old.Q_Code) 
     WHERE QAH.Q_Code=old.Q_Code AND QAH.S_Email=old.S_Email;   
END//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: That will generated the error again because `END;//` should be `END //`.

Comment: The code is working fine now. Thanks for the answer.